# How to store the outputs from three different tables into one table?

Tags: sql, sas

I have three datasets/tables created by three different macros: one for numerical field, one for categorical field, and one for date field. When I call the macros I do

```
%pnum(databasename, tablename, variablename)
%pcat(databasename, tablename, variablename)
%pdate(databasename, tablename, variablename)
```

The first table (table1) looks like:

```
databasename | tablename| variablename| mean| N| missing | stddev
```

The second table (table2) looks like:

```
databasename | tablename| variablename| S | N| missing| stddev| completeness
```

The third table (table3) looks like:

```
databasename | tablename| variablename| minimum date| maximum date| mean
```

I would like to create one table (final table) which contains data values from the previous three macros:

```
databasename | tablename| variablename|  mean| N| missing | stddev |S| completeness
```

I tried to create a `libname results` to store the results and use `proc sql` to create a new table:

```
proc sql;
create table result.final as 
select t1.*
,t2.S
,t2.compleness
,t3.minimum_date
,t3.maximum_date
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.date=t2.date
left join table3 t3
on t1.date=t2.date;
quit;
```

where `date` is common to all the tables (is a table grouping field). 
However, but this does not work when I run the macros: for example, I run `pnum` and I receive the error message

> the table final does not exist

.

The error is due to this part of code:

```
proc sql;
insert into results.final;
t1.*
from table1 t1;
quit;
```

Probably I am trying to insert the columns and its values in a dataset not created yet.

Then my question: how can I create a new dataset, using that libname, that collects and stores all the values from the tables created by those macros, as shown in final table? What I would like to do at the end is to create this code into a new macro.

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Will you ever need to overwrite a row, such as when a specific database/table/variable is remeasured at a later date?  Also the first sql code in the question does match the table descriptions -- the three parts are not shown as to have a data column and the left join t3 is incorrect (on t1.date=t2.date)

Comment: Why are you trying to join on DATE when that variable is not in any of the sources? Do you need to merge the data or just stack the observations?  If you need to merge them then which source for the common variables (MEAN, STDDEV) do you want to use? Or would you want to rename those variables so that they different variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you able to merge the datasets together and then assign it to a library?

```
    data [library].final;
merge table1 table2 table3;
by date;
run;
```

Comment: What would it happen to the columns in common in this case? I thought of joining the table but probably I was wrong

Comment: Is it also wrong to create an empty table and then fill it? I was considering different ways to proceed, but I do not know if they work and how to implement them correctly

Comment: columns with the same name will be replaced in a proc sql / merge statement, if you're looking to keep all the columns you could concatenate the table name (or an abbreviation) to each of the column names beforehand - clever use of a macro and dictionary.tables would work here.

nothing wrong with creating an empty table but typically it can be avoided if you're going to populate it immediately afterwards anyway, there are only a few niche scenarios where this would be the preferred solution

Comment: What if one of these tables would non exist?

Comment: you will get an error in that case. if there are multiple tables to merge and there's a chance that one or more doesn't exist, use a consistent naming standard to name the tables and then merge them together using the wildcard symbol ":". for example data mergeddatsets; merge table:; run; -- this will merge all the tables that start with "TABLE"

Answer (score 1):

Use a data step + `SET` to append the data sets together.

```
data want;
 set t1 t2 t3 indsname=source;
 dsname = source; *This will store the name of the input data set;
run;
```